# Memorising Cases' Endings

Tags: падежи

Is there an easier or fun way that I could memorise the cases endings?

Comment: memorization of case endings is in itself a lot of fun ))))

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is a better way, but what you ask seems to be a challenge which has been explored in the Russian teaching community - how to help foreign students to memorize case endings?

In this one  article I have found for you, they offer a couple of systematic tables based partly on an assumptions learning can happen through attributing cases to already well-known phrases, like (note: caps are to designate endings, not stressed syllables):

(masculine, neuter      adjectives + nouns SINGULAR)

2. Genitive **ПриятнОГО  аппетитА!**
3. Dative **ДорогОМУ  другУ на память!**
4. Instrumental **С  НовЫМ  годОМ!**
5. Prepositional **Я на седьмОМ  небЕ!**

While they do not proceed like this with all declinations, maybe you build on that somehow with your own examples.

Костюк Нина Александровна
[НЕКОТОРЫЕ АСПЕКТЫ ПРЕПОДАВАНИЯ  РКИ  НА  НАЧАЛЬНОМ ЭТАПЕ  (как запомнить падежные окончания)](http://ip-r.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BA-%D0%9D.A.-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A0%D0%9A%D0%98-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.docx)

Comment: When a word has a syllable capitalized it suggests that is where the stress is, but приятного, другу, and новым are not stressed where your examples are capitalized.  On the matter of foreigners learning cases, I don't think this is something achieved by a "fun" easy technique. Only sustained practice with reading and writing will burn the patterns into the brain.

Comment: capitilizing here is not stress but marking the endings

Answer (score 2):

I remember a verse from kids' magazine *Трамвай:*

> **И:** Шла весной по льду *свинь**я,*** ей попалась *полынь**я.***
>
> **Р:** Плюх! Торчит из *полынь**и*** только хвостик от *свинь**и.***
>
> **Д:** Мы — скорее к *полынь**е,*** мы хотим помочь *свинь**е.***
>
> **В:** Сами чуть не в *полынь**ю,*** но спасли-таки *свинь**ю.***
>
> **Т:** Недовольны мы *свинь**ёй:*** разве шутят с *полынь**ёй?***
>
> **П:** Вспоминайте о *свинь**е,*** чтоб не плавать в *полынь**е.***

Comment: Я заплюсовал, потому что журнал "Трамвай" - ну как не заплюсовать) - но замечу, что нам эта мнемоника кажется полезной потому что мы знаем язык - я сомневаюсь, что человеку, которые языка не знает это стихотворение поможет  - ну потому что он будет забывать эти окончания, на которых строится рифма.

Comment: I agree with @shabunc, this verse is helpful to Russian children, but the sentences are too difficult for adults learning the language. It also covers just one declension. Instead I recommend the 25 sentences given in this paper: http://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/etd/1171/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with easier - I'm a strong proponent of not trying to memorize any kind of rules but rather phrases in a whole - just like child don't know anything about grammar but speaks, makes mistakes and gradually makes them less.

**Honestly, there's no fun way to learn language.**
But may be just listing some basic list of rules will be helpful.

Well, let me start with

**Dative**

1. If the feminine or masculine noun ends with `-a`, it changes to `-e`, like in `мама` → `маме
2. If the feminine or masculine none ends with `-я`, it changes to `-и` like in `дядя` → `дяде`
3. For all the rest nouns of masculine and neuter gender which ends with palatalized (soft) consonant or with a vowel, -ю is added, like in `конь` →`коню`.
4. For all the rest nouns of masculine and neuter gender, `-у` is added, like in `сон` → `сну`. Be warned though that vowel (as you can see from previous example) can be dropped -or added - and there's anything you can do but memorize such words.
5. Finally, all the rest nouns of feminine - that is, all nouns ending with `-ь` - `-и`is added instead, like in - `боль` → `боли`

Nouns from #1-2 belongs to the so-called first declension group - let's nouns from #1 and #2 be 1a and 1b accordingly, from #3-4 - to the second one (so, 2a and 2b), and #5 is actually about nouns that belong to the third such group. There are also group called `разносклоняемые`, which are basically exceptions.

Ok, let's move further.

**Instrumental**

1. 1a, `-a` changes to `-ой`, `мама` → `мамой`
2. 1b, `-я` changes to `-eй`, `дядя` → `дядей`
3. 2a,  ending changes to `-ом`, `сон`→ `сном`,
4. 2b,  ending changes to `-eм`/`-ём`,`море` → `морем`; `конь` → `конём`
5. 3, ending changes to `-ю`, `боль` → `болью`
6. Bunch of exceptions ending with `-ей`, `-ею`.

**Prepositional**

1. 1a, `-a` changes to `-е`, `мама` → `маме`
2. 1b, `-я` changes to `-и` or `-е`, `дядя` → `дяде` but `линия` → `линией`
3. 2a, 2b ending changes to `-е`, `сон`→ `сне`,
4. 2 ending with `-ие`, changes to `-ии`, like in `сочинение` → `сочинении`
5. 2 ending with `ий` - changes to `ии`, like in `гений` → `гении`
6. 3 + exceptions, ending changes to `-и`, `боль` → `боли`

**Genitive**

1. 1a, `-a` changes to `-ы`, `мама` → `мамы`
2. 1b, `-я` changes to `-eй`, `дядя` → `дяди`
3. 2a,  ending changes to `-a`, `сон`→ `снa`,
4. 2b,  ending changes to `-a`,`море` → `моря`; `конь` → `коня`
5. 3, ending changes to `-и`, `боль` → `боли`

**Accusative**

1. 1a, `-a` changes to `-у`, `мама` → `маму`
2. 1b, `-я` changes to `-ю`, `дядя` → `дядю`
3. 2a,  ending changes to `-a`, `сон`→ `снa`,
4. 2b,  ending changes to `-я`,`море` → `моря`; `конь` → `коня`
5. 3, ending changes to `-и`, `боль` → `боли`

This is simplified as much as possible. Just like I've said, there are some exceptions, there are some obsolete endings that still can be use, there are some variations for animate and inanimate nouns. Finally, of course, you need to memorize rules for plural as well. But this is that exactly rare case when I believe that it's better to have a separate answer on this.

Comment: Why are you discharging mnemonic rules? They are usually fun and they help learning a language (or something else)

Comment: @Alissa they help to learn small sets of items, like, don't know sequence of entities - colors, cases etc. When it comes to learning any kind of rules in my experience it's just not working.

Comment: I understand that for some things there are no mnemonics, 'cause there are too many cases or something. But I think you are being too hard saying "there is no fun way to learn language".

Comment: @Alissa, well, there's no fun way to become a good soccer player, a developer, a  musician - it's all about quite a lot of hard work. Unfortunately. The fun part is the satisfaction that you've achieved something, but the very process can be very painful. and sometimes quite boresome )